# Update a component inside of a bunch of component (*ngFor) angular

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components

```
                        <mat-card class="Board col-md-2 col-sm-2" *ngFor="let board of boards">
                            <mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-title>{{board.boardName}}</mat-card-title>
                                <button mat-button mat-flat-button
                                    [matMenuTriggerData]="{id : board.id, name:board.boardName}"
                                    [matMenuTriggerFor]="boardmenu">
                                    <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon>
                                </button>

                            </mat-card-header>
                            <app-todo [Id]="board.id"></app-todo>

                        </mat-card>
```

so im making my kanban board webapp, and there is a problem when i tried to update the value of this TodoList in side of , it did update though, but i can't pass the value of this board todolist to the others board todolist inside of ngfor

```
<mat-menu #todoMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-id="id">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeColor(1,id)">Imediately</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeColor(2,id)">Importance</button>
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="moveMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{id : id}">Move To</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteTodo(id)">Delete</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>


<mat-menu #moveMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-id="id">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let board of boardlist" (click)="moveTodo(id,board.id)">{{board.boardName}}</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

you can see when i try to moveTodo by a click event, not by using drag and drop of material cdk, i can't get the other board todolist update it's value and rerender the list
is there any way so i could just update the value of the array in side of the board *ngFor ?

Comment: could you please show us your component logic for this `moveTodo()` and also your board data.

Comment: sorry i deleted it before, thing is im trying to change a todo's properties named boardId then from the Todo array(let's said boardid = 1) i remove it and push it in to the Todo array(of boardid = 2) so i could update it without refresh the page, but i dont know how to do the 'push' step